# Domain Controller issue

Tags: ip, domain-controller, active-directory

Our DC was having issues so we built a new server to replace it. It's running 2003 (same as previous DC). I ran DCpromo and transferred roles to the new DC. Now Users are having issues connecting to the internet (169.254). Also I did not set up DHCP. This backup DC will be replaced within the next few weeks. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. What issues was the old DC having? 2. Is the old DC still on the network/domain? 3. Did the old DC run DHCP? You say 169.254 - I take it you mean the clients aren't getting a DHCP address?

Comment: *Why* did you not install DHCP?

Comment: I wanted to install DHCP but was told not to by my boss. He said that it shouldn't be an issue, which I believe it is. The reason we are getting rid of the old one is because it was freezing consistently. The old DC is still connected and it did run DHCP

Comment: @Mike To be clear, is the old DC **still** running DHCP? Either way, yes, DHCP is the root cause of your issue but you need to ensure you don't end up with two DHCP servers on the same network. Either fix whatever s wrong with your old DHCP server, or remove the role and recreate it all on the new server.

Comment: yes it is still running DHCP.

Comment: @Mike In which case it sounds broke to me. I'd definitely kill DHCP on that machine and recreate it on the new one.

Comment: Run a packet capture on a client and on the old DC. Run ipconfig/release and ipconfig/renew on the client. Look for the DHCP traffic from the client to the server and back to the client. Seeing the traffic (or not seeing it) on both ends should give you a clue as to what's happening (or not happening).

Answer (score 3):

You did not install DHCP, and the client's are getting a default ARPA IP because you don't have DHCP running.

Install DHCP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable DHCP on your new server and ensure your old one is no longer a DHCP server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to say installing DHCP would be a good step - this is why your clients are getting this type of IP address.

Comment: Because I can not answer:

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you need DHCP, it's what provides your clients with an IP-address. Also, make sure you put your new DC server as prim DNS.

Comment: So The issue was the DHCP server was saying that it wasn't Authorized on the older server. I went to Authorize the service it said that it was already authorized. I restarted the service  and DHCP came back up. Had clients do a Ipconfig release/renew. 

Thanks for all your help and quick responses.